Calculate the mean of values in a list grouped by labels
I have an efficiency problem when trying to solve the following in a python program: suppose we have a list huge_list containing tuples like the following: (label1, label2, numerical_value) Where label* are just strings that are used to know what the meaning of numerical_value is in my program context. This list might be up to 10million elements long, in a normal application of the program. What i want to compute is, given a fixed string x, the mean of the values "numerical_value" contained in the list such that its corresponding tuple label2 equals x. The obvious idea is just to make a list comprehension that filters the tuples meeting the condition, and then compute the mean over this reduced list: interesting_values = [value for _, label2, dist in huge_list if label2==x] mean = np.mean(interesting_values)
But as the list is huge, this operation takes an excessively long time to complete. Moreover, it's convenient for my program to have these values stored in such a way since i need to order them, and thus another structure like a dictionary:
values_dict[label2][label1] = numerical_value

Would cause more problems in other parts of the program. I also want to avoid creating both data structures if possible. Another possibility I considered is, at the part of the program where these numerical values are calculated, which would mean calculate them fixing each label2, and the computing the mean on the moment and store it, but this would suppose a big change in the program, and specially in the way it is parallelized (fixing label1 for each process, since the set of label2 values is expected to be of a much bigger order of magnitude than label1, and doing it the other way around would make it much slower.) Is there an alternative way to calculate this with the list huge_list in an efficient way, or should I look for a different way of storing the values? I thought about using pandas dataframes, as these would allow me to order the values and also calculate the mean, but I am not sure if this would improve the efficiency. I have also discovered the cuDF library, in a fast lookup that I made to see if GPUs could allow me to parallelize things in some way, but I'm also not sure if it would help since we are not talking about operations between dataframes, but about calculations inside the dataframe itself.
I expected the list comprehension described above to solve my problem efficiently, but as it doesn't, I want to find a way to do it in a more efficient way without changing my data structure due to the way these values are calculated by my program.

pandas would absolutely improve the speed, but it might end up using more memory

Which part is slower? Reducing the list, or computing the mean?

Pandas will be considerably slower (on my test around 5x slower using random values) because of the time to form the DataFrame. What do you consider to be an excessive time? BTW there is an error in your code snippet - value and dist.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Does the combination of label1 and label2 always produce the same value? For instance if label1 is "x" and label2 is "y" will "x","y" always be ex: "6"? If so, you could speed this up with memorization.

I suspect using pandas will improve the speed of computation. Here's some sample code that you might find helpful.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np   # needed for generating dataset
import random        # needed for generating dataset

# generate dataset
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed = 2024)
names = ["anya", "bert", "coco", "darren"]
fruit = ["apple", "banana", "clementine", "durian"]
n_repeat = 3
big_list = [(n,f,rng.integers(10,20)) 
            for n in names 
            for f in fruit
            for _ in range(n_repeat)]
rng.shuffle(big_list)

# convert list format to dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame(data = big_list, columns = ["label1","label2","value"])

# compute mean for one category
print("mean for clementine:")
print(df.loc[df.label2 == "clementine", "value"].mean())
print()

## mean for clementine:
## 14.75

# compute mean for each group
print("means for each group:")
print(df.groupby("label2")["value"].mean())

## means for each group:
## label2
## apple         13.666667
## banana        13.166667
## clementine    14.750000
## durian        15.666667

